# how do i use reducer to update a global variable

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I need to pass a variable between two files, this variable will store data(userId) gotten from file one(fetched from an api) so that I can use the variable as a parameter in an endpoint in file two. I have used  redux toolkit to create a global state but I can not figure out how to use reducers(from a third file slice.js) to update the global state to the data gotten from file one . I actually do not know how to go about this at all.

file one :
inside this file ,there  are buttons rendered dynamically from an api that leads to another page when any of the buttons is clicked. On this other page , there is gonna be some information displayed depending on the id gotten.

```
const [usersData, setUsersData] = userState([]);

useEffect({
fetchData()
});

export default function FileOne(){
return(
<>
  {usersData.map(userData => (
    <Link to='/fileTwo'>
       <button>{userData.id}</button>
    </Link>
  )}
</>
)
}
```

so i have used redux toolkit to create a global variable

slice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    userId:0
    // Your global state properties here (e.g., count: 0, data: [])
};

 export const idSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'id',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getUserId(state){
          
        },
        // Reducer functions to update the state (e.g., increment(state) { ... })
    },
});
export const { getUserId} = idSlice.actions;
export default idSlice.reducer;
```

what i need help with is how i'm gonna update userId(the global state)to each user's Id depending on the button clicked inside file one

Comment: You would dispatch an action to the store to update the state, and use the `useSelector` hook to subscribe to state. Redux-Toolkit explains all this, see [Getting Started](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started). Can you [edit] to describe in actual detail what the issue or problem is or what you need specific help with and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with. See [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: i just added an edit, pls do check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to set a selected user id into the state then these are the changes/additions I'd suggest.

- Add a new `setUserId` action to set the currently selected `userId`
- Dispatch the `setUserId` action in the button's `onClick` handler
- Read the current `userId` state value in the target component

Example:

```js
const initialState = {
  userId: null
  // Your global state properties here (e.g., count: 0, data: [])
};

export const idSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'id',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ....,
    setUserId: (state, action) => {
      state.userId = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  ....,
  setUserId,
} = idSlice.actions;
```

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setUserId } from '../path/to/idSlice;'

export default function FileOne() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return usersData.map(userData => (
    <Link key={userData.id} to='/fileTwo'>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(setUserId(userData.id))}>
        {userData.id}
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const FileTwo = () => {
  const selectedUserId = useSelector(state => state.id.userId);

  ...
};
```

For what it's worth this seems like rather transient state and likely doesn't need to be anything stored in the Redux store. Since you are using a `Link` component (*assumed React-Router library usage here*) and effecting a navigation action you could likely just include the user id in the navigation action, either in the URL path, i.e. `"/fileTwo/:userId"`, or in the route state.

- Passing `userData.id` in route state:

  ```
  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

  export default function FileOne() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return usersData.map(userData => (
      <Link key={userData.id} to='/fileTwo' state={{ userId: userData.id }}>
        {userData.id}
      </Link>
    );
  }
  ```

  ```js
  import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

  const FileTwo = () => {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    const { userId } = state ?? {};

    ...
  };
  ```
- Passing `userData.id` in URL path segment:

  ```
  <Route
    path="/fileTwo/:userId?"
    element={<FileTwo />}
  </Route>
  ```

  ```
  import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

  export default function FileOne() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return usersData.map(userData => (
      <Link key={userData.id} to={`/fileTwo/${userData.id}`}>
        {userData.id}
      </Link>
    );
  }
  ```

  ```js
  import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

  const FileTwo = () => {
    const { userId } = useParams();

    ...
  };
  ```